How to redirect to Home Screen even if we launch other Controller for First time in .NET core
I was working with .NET Windows applications and moving to Web Application.
In my application, the Home controller and its index action are designated as the default controller and action method. Within the Home controller, I am initializing application metadata (First name, last name, Roles, etc ) in static variables, which are intended for use across various screens.
However, I have observed that users are directly accessing controllers such as View Details and Add New User, thereby circumventing the Home Controller. This results in the static variables not being initialized properly.
To address this issue, I would like to implement a mechanism that ensures my application redirects to the Home Controller, regardless of the initial page the user attempts to access. This would allow for the necessary values to be initialized prior to any other interactions.
As a developer transitioning from Windows applications, I find this shift to web development to be somewhat challenging.
The primary issues I am encountering include:
I wish to redirect my application to Home/index (configured as the default in program.cs) even if the user attempts to access any other controller for first time.

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


If redirection is not feasible, I need to find a way to initialize the values in static variables, irrespective of which URL is accessed (e.g, View Details, Add User, etc.). I am seeking a more effective approach to implement this initialization, considering that I currently have 10 controllers and 32 views.

Your requirements sound like somewhat "Authentcation", Authentication requires users to sign in ahead otherwise the website should redirect to sign in page. We can use asp.net core authentication mechanism to achieve it easily. But in your scenario,  we don't have a builtin scheme to validate the custom application metadata, so that we could create a custom middleware/action filter to valdiate the metadata, then control the request to redirect to home page on keep going on to the target endpoint.


However, I have observed that users are directly accessing controllers such as View Details and Add New User, thereby circumventing the Home Controller. This results in the static variables not being initialized properly.

Well, users are going to use direct links to sub pages the have, or access your site in any way the like, so I'm not sure redirecting to home page would be good user experience, unless we are talking about redirecting to login page unauthorized users.
I'm not sure what do you need those static variables for, however what I would suggest is to create some class holding these, inject it as a Singleton instance using your DI container and, if needed, fetch all your metadata needed using lazy loading, for example using Lazy<> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-8.0
How to inject a singleton: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#service-registration-methods

Let's say, the static variable requries to be filled after an user interactive operation in HomeController, then we can create a filter to do the validation, checking whether the initialization task has completed or not.
In my sample below, I worked in an MVC app so that when I run the app it will go to home page directly, I put the initialization task in Privacy action. And my action filter will do the validation.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<InitializationFilter>();
});

public class InitializationFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var controllerName = context.RouteData.Values["controller"]?.ToString().ToLower();
        var actionName = context.RouteData.Values["action"]?.ToString().ToLower();
        // Redirect to initialization page if not yet initialized
        if (!(controllerName == "home" && actionName == "privacy") && !GlobalConfigService._isInitialized) {
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Privacy", "Home", null);
        }

    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // Do nothing after the action executes
    }
}

public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    GlobalConfigService._isInitialized = true;
    return View();
}

public static class GlobalConfigService
{
    public static bool _isInitialized { get; set; } = false;
}

But if we say the initialiaztion task doesn't require an interacitve operation, we can put the init realization method into the action filter directly so that it will make sure before hit any action method, the app already completed the init.
